# Windows Phone 8.1 Airplane mode event

Tags: events, windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, airplane-mode

I want an application (windows Phone 8.1) which shutdown when Airplane mode is ON, and start again when Airplane mode OFF.

For this I need event of Airplane mode ON/OFF. I did not found any API for this. Can you please tell me how to achieve in WP8.1.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: WinRT app or Silverlight?

Answer (score 0):

There is no event that I know of for AirPlane mode.   You do have an event telling you when network connectivity has changed

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh487166%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj835820.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any direct API that accesses the status of Airplane Mode directly but essentially it shuts down network availability so you could test for that using the  [DeviceNetworkInformation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) class. (It's a good idea to test this on a device but I believe this would simulate Airplane Mode)

```
public bool IsAirplaneMode()
{
    bool[] networks = new bool[4] { DeviceNetworkInformation.IsNetworkAvailable, DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataEnabled, DeviceNetworkInformation.IsCellularDataRoamingEnabled, DeviceNetworkInformation.IsWiFiEnabled };
    return (networks.Count(n => n) < 1);
}
```

If you'd like to ask the user to turn it on or off, you can do that by [How to set Airplane mode in Windows Phone using C#](http://mobileosgeek.com/how-to-set-airplane-mode-in-windows-phone-using-c/)